# Why can't Rust do more complex type inference?

Tags: rust, type-inference

In [Chapter 3](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch03-05-control-flow.html) of *The Rust Programming Language*, the following code is used as an example for a kind of type inference that Rust cannot manage:

```
fn main() {
    let condition = true;

    let number = if condition { 5 } else { "six" };

    println!("The value of number is: {}", number);
}
```

with the explanation that:

> Rust needs to know at compile time what type the `number` variable is, definitively, so it can verify at compile time that its type is valid everywhere we use `number`. Rust wouldn’t be able to do that if the type of `number` was only determined at runtime; the compiler would be more complex and would make fewer guarantees about the code if it had to keep track of multiple hypothetical types for any variable.

I'm not certain I understand the rationale, because the example does seem like something where a simple compiler could infer the type.

What exactly makes this kind of type inference so difficult? In this case, the value of *condition* can be clearly inferred at compile time (it's true), and so thus the type of number can be too (it's `i32`?).

I can see how things *could* become a lot more complicated, if you were trying to infer types across multiple compilation units for instance, but is there something about this specific example that would add a lot of complexity to the compiler?

Comment: What is the type of `number` then? Should it *change* at runtime? Why do you think this code has anything to do with inference?

Comment: It's an i32... 

If I change _condition_, then the compiled type could be changed to a String.

I get that there are more complex examples where the type is ambiguous, but it seems pretty simple to handle this sort of case: a good compiler is likely to optimize away the redundant conditional statement anyway. When it does that, it'll be left with an unambiguous type (since the expression resolves to 5).

Comment: @Shepmaster I think it has to do with type inference because the canonical book for learning the language explicitly says it has to do with type inference...

The type doesn't need to change at runtime, because it can be explicitly inferred at compile time in the given example.

Comment: It's not a type inference concern. Even if you explicitly put `let number: i32 = ...`, it still won't compile.

Comment: *the canonical book for learning the language explicitly says it has to do with type inference* — the word "infer" doesn't appear anywhere [on the page you linked](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch03-05-control-flow.html); that's why I'm confused at the connection between the two.

Comment: *it seems pretty simple to handle this sort of case* — Let's say this feature existed; under what circumstances would you find it useful? You can't rely on it because as soon as the condition isn't trivially evaluated then your code can no longer compile.

Comment: @Shepmaster I don't expect it's very useful most of the time, but I've written things like it when I wrote a type system into an interpreter for a Forth dialect. 

The question is simply _why_ it doesn't do inference here. If the answer is "This case is not common enough to be worth handling", that's not the same as the one the book gave (which was the source of my confusion).

Comment: @Shepmaster Also, regarding the book, you're right that it doesn't explicitly say type inference, but come on: the type of _number_ is not explicitly stated, so it must be inferred by the compiler. My question is about why it doesn't handle this inference. What tag would you rather this be filed under?

Comment: @WesleyWiser Great, that sounds like an answer that you should post. Maybe I asked this question strangely, but I'm surprised by the hostile response from the community at large. I really want to know why the language was designed this way. It's clearly not for the reason given in the book.

Comment: I also find it interesting that you've decided to not quote the preceding two sentences (emphasis mine): *The expression in the `if` block evaluates to an integer, and the expression in the `else` block evaluates to a string. This won’t work because **variables must have a single type***. And like SilvioMayolo mentions, you can give explicit types to everything here, removing any inference.

Comment: @WesleyWiser Fair enough. Thanks for the constructive work anyway.

Comment: There's no hostility intended, just actual, honest perplexity. You would prefer to use a language where `typeof(if A { X } else { Y })` is determined by `A`, `X` and `Y` instead of just `X` (so long as `X` == `Y`) and that's confusing to me. There's no reason for the compiler writers to spend time working on such features that have such limited use that seemingly no one wants.

Comment: @Shepmaster It's really not a question of preference. The book says the type is indeterminate because it would make the compiler "more complex and would make fewer guarantees". It's clear that, in this case, the complexity added is close to zero (just check the type after checking whether you can optimize out the conditional), and there's no change in the guarantees it can make. I don't need this feature, I just want to know why it's not there.

Also, I mean this in the best possible way, but if this is "no hostility intended" for you, you should take a course in interpersonal communication.

Comment: *the complexity added is close to zero (just check the type after checking whether you can optimize out the conditional)* — If that's the case, then submit an RFC to change the language, ideally with a parallel pull request implementing the feature. I would guess that everything is on the complete other side of the coin, that it's **not trivial** to add. Since no one wants it, no one has added it. Why waste time developing such a feature?

Comment: As for the book, the text isn't intending for you to focus on the fact that `condition = true`. Instead, pretend that the code is `fn example(condition: boolean) { let number = if condition { 5 } else { "six" }; println!("The value of number is: {}", number); }`. In that case, the value of `condition` is indeterminate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177232/discussion-between-shepmaster-and-john-doucette).

Answer (score 12):

There are three main reasons I can think of:

### 1. Action at a distance effects

Let's suppose the language worked that way. Since we're extending type inference, we might as well make the language even smarter and have it infer return types as well. This allows me to write something like:

```
pub fn get_flux_capacitor() {
  let is_prod = true;

  if is_prod { FluxCapacitor::new() } else { MovieProp::new() }
}
```

And elsewhere in my project, I can get a `FluxCapacitor` by calling that function. However, one day, I change `is_prod` to `false`. Now, instead of getting an error that my function is returning the wrong type, I will get errors at **every** callsite. A small change inside one function has lead to errors in entirely unchanged files! That's pretty weird.

(If we don't want to add inferered return types, just imagine it's a very long function instead.)

### 2. Compiler internals exposed

What happens in the case where it's not so simple? Surely this should be the same as the above example:

```
pub fn get_flux_capacitor() {
  let is_prod = (1 + 1) == 2;

  ...
}
```

But how far does that extend? The compiler's constant propagation is mostly an implementation detail. You don't want the types in your program to depend on how smart this version of the compiler is.

### 3. What did you actually mean?

As a human looking at this code, it looks like something is missing. Why are you branching on `true` at all? Why not just write `FluxCapacitor::new()`? Perhaps there's logic missing to check and see if a `env=DEV` environment variable is missing. Perhaps a trait object should actually be used so that you can take advantage of runtime polymorphism.

In this kind of situation where you're asking the computer to do something that doesn't seem quite right, Rust often chooses to throw its hands up and ask you to fix the code.

Comment: Could you annotate which of these reasons are the ones that the Rust language has chosen? These all feel opinion based.

Comment: *Compiler internals exposed* — this can be solved by only relying on `const fn`

Comment: It’s worth noting that the idea of a “compile-time constant” isn’t an implementation detail for C or C++.

Comment: @DietrichEpp even there, it kind of is. The standards guarantee some of it, but most compilers are able to do a lot more that what the standard mandates (which is good), and expose it sometimes without the user's knowledge (which is less good). Work on C++ `constexpr`s has made dealing with this simpler and more consistent, but I'm pretty sure some compiler will accept more than other even when they both claim to follow the standard.

Comment: @mcarton: So you're saying that some compilers are more permissive and accept code that other compilers don't accept, therefore it is better to not do any constant folding in the type checker? I'm not sure I follow the argument. The fact that some compilers are more permissive than others is pervasive and affects programs in many ways, the identification of compile-time constants doesn't seem special. The idea that it "depends on how smart this version of your compiler is" is too much of an exaggeration these days.

Comment: I'm not saying they shouldn't do constant folding, of course they should! I'm saying a some implementation details still leak to the user and some compiler are able to do more (rather than being more permissive). Also, `constexpr` has little to do with constant folding (as in, you don't need to use `constexpr` to get constant folding, and compilers can do fold a lot more than what the standard mandates they do).

Comment: And "depends on how smart this version of your compiler is" doesn't hold for desktops, but it still holds on industrial embedded platforms were you get shipped with a basically undocumented compiler that support some kind of C bastard. Those are great. But yeah, that's not relevant to the OP.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, in this very specific case (where `condition=true` statically), the compiler could be made able to detect that the `else` branch is unreachable and therefore `number` must be 5.

This is just a contrived example, though... in the more general case, the value of `condition` would only be dynamically known at runtime.
It's in that case, as other have said, that inference becomes hard to implement.

On that topic, there are two things I haven't seen mentioned yet.

1. The Rust language design tends to err on the side of doing things as
   explicitly as possible
2. Rust type inference is only local

On point #1, the explicit way for Rust to deal with the "this type can be one of multiple types" use case are [enums](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch06-01-defining-an-enum.html).
You can define something like this:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Whatsit {
    Num(i32),
    Text(&'static str),
}
```

and then do `let number = if condition { Num(5) } else { Text("six") };`

On point #2, let's see how the enum (while wordier) is the preferred approach in the language. In the example from the book we just try printing the value of `number`. 
In a more real-case scenario we would at one point use `number` for something other than printing.

This means passing it to another function or including it in another type. Or (to even enable use of `println!`) implementing the `Debug` or `Display` traits on it. Local inference means that (if you can't name the type of `number` in Rust), you would not be able to do any of these things.
Suppose you want to create a function that does something with a `number`;
with the enum you would write:

```
fn do_something(number: Whatsit)
```

but without it...

```
fn do_something(number: /* what type is this? */)
```

In a nutshell, you're right that in principle it IS doable for the compiler to synthesize a type for `number`. For instance, the compiler might create an anonymous enum like `Whatsit` above when compiling that code. 
But you - the programmer - would not know the name of that type, would not be able to refer to it, wouldn't even know what you can do with it (can I multiply two "numbers"?) and this would greatly limit its usefulness.

A similar approach was followed for instance to add closures to the language. The compiler would know what specific type a closure has, but you, the programmer, would not. If you're interested I can try finding out discussions on the difficulties that the approach introduced in the design of the language.